# json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) in flask python

Tags: python, flask

I created mini project with flask for watching movies using netu.ac links.
i made /admin page where i can add to database
[admin page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXUl0.png)

When i press delete button i delete it but get this error: [ERROR](https://ctxt.io/2/AABQlDGMEA)

app.py:

```
@app.route('/admin', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def admin_dashboard():
    # Check if the user is logged in
    if 'username' not in session:
        return redirect(url_for('login'))

    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Handle form submission to add or remove movies or TV shows
        action = request.form['action']
        

        if action == 'add_movie':
            # Get movie details from the form
            title = request.form['title']
            category = request.form['category']
            # Add the movie to the Supabase database
            supabase.table('movies').insert({'title': title, 'category': category}).execute()
        


        elif action == 'add_tvshow':
            # Get TV show details from the form
            tvshow_name = request.form['tvshow_name']
            episode_number = int(request.form['episode_number'])
            category = request.form['category']
            # Add the TV show to the Supabase database
            supabase.table('tvshows').insert({'tv_show_name': tvshow_name, 'episode_number': episode_number, 'category': category}).execute()
        


        elif action == 'remove':
            item_type = request.form['type']
            item_id = str(int(request.form['id']))  # Convert to string

            if item_type == 'movie':
                # Remove the movie from the database
                supabase.table('movies').delete().eq('id', item_id).execute()
            elif item_type == 'tvshow':
                # Remove the TV show from the database
                supabase.table('tvshows').delete().eq('id', item_id).execute()
            else:
                pass
```

and inside admin.html:

```
    function deleteItem(type, id) {
      var confirmDelete = confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item?');
      if (confirmDelete) {
        // Send an AJAX request to delete the item from the server
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', '/admin', true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        xhr.onload = function() {
          if (xhr.status === 200) {
            // Item deleted successfully, remove it from the DOM
            var item = document.getElementById(type + '-' + id);
            item.remove();
          } else {
            // Error occurred while deleting the item
            console.error('Error deleting item:', xhr.responseText);
          }
        };
        xhr.send('action=remove&type=' + type + '&id=' + id);
      }
    }
```

i tried to fix it but without succes

Comment: Please note that the error you shared contains "SECRET", I believe you do not want to share this with everyone.